# :hover is not working; how to correct it?

Tags: css, hover

```
.signUp 
{
-moz-border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
-webkit-border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #888888;
cursor : pointer;
}
.signUp :hover
{
-moz-border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
-webkit-border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;

}
```

This is not working; how can I fix it? The class is placed in a `<span>` element.

Comment: `.signUp:hover` remove the space in between.

Comment: Both the classes have same styles you won't see the difference.

Comment: You're not changing anything.  What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I think he wants to remove box shadow

Comment: That would not be apparent either. If he wished to remove the box-shadow instruction, he should have explicitly done so.

Comment: add box-shadow:none; in .signup:hover if you want to remove box shadow on hover otherwise it will show no change on hover

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code

```
.signUp 
{
-moz-border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
-webkit-border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #888888;
cursor : pointer;
}
.signUp:hover
{
-moz-border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
-webkit-border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
box-shadow:none;

}
```

Answer (score -1):

You ***:hover*** is *remove spacae*.

html

```
<span>HoverTest</span>
```

css

```
span{
 -moz-border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
 box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #888888;
 cursor : pointer;
 color:#ccc;
 border:1px solid #ddd;

}
span:hover{
  -moz-border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
   color:#aaa;
   border:1px solid red;
}
```

## [SEEDEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kisspa/5S8UJ/)